# General approach to find branch points of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Isn't there a general way to find the branch points of a complex function? I mean, one cannot just go around every point to see if the function is multi-valued. Isn't there some sort of classification letting know how to deal with functions of a special type?

Perhaps I'm asking this because I haven't digest the concept of branch point well. I've been reading that a branch point is a singularity, but don't understand the difference between a branch point and a singular point which is not a branch point! I know that the function is not continuous at a branch point; so it can't be analytic also, right?

Comment: of what function ? it depends on if you have an expression for it on some disk, or for the whole complex plane, or if you only have a complicated power series on some disk, or if you only defined it by some functional/differential  equation, etc.

Comment: and in "singular point" the key-word is "point". $f(z)$ has a singular point at $a$ if it is holomorphic on some neighborhood of $a$ except at $a$. look at $f(z) = \ln(z)$ or $f(z) = z^{1/2}$, it is not holomorphic on any pointed neighborhood of $0$, hence $0$ is not a singular point. and it has a branch cut because it is discontinuous on some line (but it is holomorphic on the neighborhood of that line).

Comment: @user1952009 So you mean the function is holomorphic on that point, but not on its neighborhood? And how do I find out if the function is not holomorphic on some neighborhood of a point?

Comment: the function is not holomorphic at that point but is holomorphic on its neighborhood. for example $f(z) = 1/z$ or $g(z) = e^{1/z}$ both are holomorphic on $0< |z| < 1$ but not at $z=0$ : hence $0$ is a singular point of those functions. now if you take $h(z) = z^{1/2}$ it is NOT holomorphic on $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon  > 0$ hence $0$ is NOT a singular point (it is a branching point of some branch cut)

Comment: and $h(z) = z^{1/2}$ is not holomorphic on $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ because if you choose the usual branch of the logarithm, hence $z = r e^{ i \theta}$ with $\theta \in ]-\pi,\pi]$ you get $h(r e^{i \theta}) = \sqrt{r} e^{i \theta / 2}$ which is discontinuous around $\theta = \pi$

Comment: z=0 is not a singular point for z^(1/2), yet it doesn't have derivatives of all orders so it can't be holomorphic, thus a branch point is neither a singular point nor a point on which the function is holomorphic, right? And the reason why z^(1/2) is not holomorphic on any neighborhood of 0 is that it's multi=valued and thus not derivable, right? By the way how do I guess if z=0 may be the branch point for this function?

Comment: no it is not really multi valued, since a function $h : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ assigns one unique complex number to each complex number. $h(z) = z^{1/2}$ in complex analysis means $h(z) \overset{def}= \exp(\frac{\ln z}{2})$ hence you choose first one branch of the logarithm, and then you get $z^{1/2}$. with the usual branch of the logarithm, i.e. with $\ln z = \ln|z| + i arg(z)$ with $arg(z) \in ]-\pi,\pi]$ you get a branch cut (a discontinuity) on the line $[0,-\infty[$ of the complex plane (exactly in the same way that the usual $\ln z$ has a branch cut on the line $[0,\infty[$).

Comment: Now I'm very much confused. I have no idea how z^(1/2) is related to an exponential function. But anyway, z^(1/2) IS multi-valued since if I change the argument of z adding a 2π, the value of the function changes sign.

Comment: great, you don't know that $z = \exp(\ln(z))$ ? and a function $z \to h(z)$ cannot be multi-valued, you have to choose one value for each $z$... that's the point of $\ln z$ or $z^{1/2}$ : we are considering a function not an algebraic equation

Comment: and if you want to capture the "multiple solutions of the equation $z = \exp(s)$" you have to leave the complex plane and go to Riemananian manifolds, see the drawing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function , that's all the difficulty with multiple branch functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch

Comment: But I was thinking first you find the branch points, then you choose the branch cut, and thus the function is no longer multi-valued. Before doing so, the function, or that algebraic equation as you say, was multi-valued for points neighboring the branch points.

Comment: Actually, I've been searching for necessary and sufficient conditions for a point to be a branch point, but came to no conclusion yet.

Comment: because you understood nothing of complex analysis ! read again what I wrote given what I wrote, and you'll find all the answers.

Comment: (I'm joking but you certainly understood nothing of $\ln z$)